# How to use XPATH for parsing HTML lists?

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I want to scrape some webpages. I am using scrapy for this. Everything works fine, but I want to 'find' a field containing numbers, which sometimes is the second, the third or the fourth 'li' in the list. Perhaps I can show you the code from the webpage:

```
<ul class="basic-product-information key-value-list">
        <li>
            <span class="key">Sprache:</span>
            <strong class="value">Unbekannt</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="key">Plattform:</span>
            <span class="value">Bücher</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="key">EAN / ISBN:</span>
            <span class="value">9783442158126</span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

The value I want to get as result is 9783442158126.

At the moment I am locating the table with this:

```
//*[@id="book-info"]/ul/li[x]/span[2]
```

I am parsing all the 'li' (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and then I get a CSV which I have to edit by hand, because I just need the ISBN - not the other things.

Is there a way to automat this? Perhaps I can tell XPATH to search for 13 digit numbers?

Thank you very much.

Best regards,
Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use and implicit `and`, concatenating expression between square brackets, and check:

1.- Its length with `string-length()` function.
2.- It's a number converting with `number()` function and comparing. It wont match for booleans because `false` is `0` whereas `true` is `1`, and neither for strings because they will be `NaN`, that is different from `NaN`, so try with:

```
//ul/li/span[2][number(text()) = number(text())][string-length() = 13]
```

---

**UPDATE**: To achieve the new requirement asked in comments, the easiest path is to use the **or** condition translated as `|` in `xpath`. To match the last `X` use `substring-before()` to get the number an increment the `string-length` by one:

```
//ul/li/span[2][number(text()) = number(text())][string-length() = 13] |
  //ul/li/span[2][number(substring-before(text(), "X")) = number(substring-before(text(), "X"))][string-length() = 14]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try to implement this in an if-function.

Comment: Thank you very much again. It worked perfect. One more problem I discovered: some of the numbers have a x in their end, e.g. 978344215812X. Do you know if there is a possibility to solve this issue?